# Cross Browser Mouse Follow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My client has requested that they they want a football to follow the mouse on their site. Totally stupid if you ask me, but he's determined to get it done.

Problem is all the scripts I have found are old school and are not cross browser.

Does anyone know of a solution either in JavaScript or jQuery that will work in all the newest browsers?

Comment: Maybe just wait the 11th of July, then he will change his mind ;) Sorry for you btw...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way with jquery:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
// e.pageY;
// e.pageX;
});
```